# Firebase data retrieval is not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to retrieve all my entries in Firebase database to populate my HTML page, but I have not been able to figure it out. I have followed many tutorials and Firebase doc, but my code is somehow not changing the HTML page and no error is shown in the console.

Basically, what I have is a list of job entries in the DB and I need to post those job entries in the format of the picture below.

[image]

So for example I have this many job entries in my FirebaseDB

[image]

I want retrieve all these entries and display four cards with their respective info and as new entries are being added they will be added to the display. Right now my code is not working and I can't figure out why. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
  <div class="row" id='Card'>
<article class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="cards"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash icon"></span>
    <hr class="divider"/>
    <h2 class="title" id="jobTitle">Job Title</h2>
    <div class="info">
      <hr class="divider"/>
      <p class="lead" id="jobDescription"><Strong>This is where Job description goes</strong></p><a class="btn btn-lg center-block" onclick="location.href = 'Specialistscard.html';">Specialists</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>



var jobTitle = document.getElementById('jobTitle');
var jobDescription= document.getElementById('jobDescription');

database = firebase.database();

var ref = database.ref('Jobs');
ref.on('value', gotData, errData);


function gotData(data) {
  console.log(data);

  var jobs = data.val();
  var keys = Object.keys(jobs);

  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var k = keys[i];
    jobTitle = jobs[k].JobTitle;
    jobDescription = jobs[k].JobDescription;

    var li = document.createElement('card', jobTitle, jobDescription)

  }
}

 function errData(err) {
  console.log('Error!');
  console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: Hi,
 I think you are assigning a string to an element, the correct form should be: `jobTitle.innerHTML = jobs [k] .JobTitle;` And ` jobDescription.innerHTML = jobs [k] .JobDescription;`

Comment: @DarwinMedina Thank you! that worked but only one entry is displayed, do you know how I can get it to duplicate that card for all the other entries in the DB?

Comment: it only display the latest entry not all entries in DB

Comment: Yep, I understand, is the for cycle, there you only replace the existing element in your html, if you want create dynamically elements you need do it different, gimme a chance to show you an example

Comment: Check my response and comment if you have any question

Comment: Thank you it worked for the dummydatajobs, but the problem i'm having is how to replace the dummydatajobs with Jobs in my database.

Comment: I just edited the answer, let know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok @Ola this is an example to how you can populate your html via javascript, also you can check out [HandleBars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) is a JS library to manipulate the DOM and have other many features.

Greetings!

```js
var dummyDataJobs = [
    {
        title: 'CEO',
        description: 'CEO Description'
    },
    {
        title: 'CTO',
        description: 'CTO Description'
    },
    {
        title: 'VP',
        description: 'VP Description'
    }
]
var container = document.getElementById('jobsContainer');
for (var index = 0; index < dummyDataJobs.length; index++) {
    var job = dummyDataJobs[index];
    var newCard = `
<div class="row" id='Card'>
<article class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="cards"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash icon"></span>
    <hr class="divider"/>
    <h2 class="title">`+ job.title + `</h2>
    <div class="info">
      <hr class="divider"/>
      <p class="lead"><Strong>`+ job.description + `</strong></p><a class="btn btn-lg center-block" onclick="location.href = 'Specialistscard.html';">Specialists</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>`;

    container.innerHTML += newCard;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="jobsContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In your case you can try the following for cycle:

```
var container = document.getElementById('jobsContainer');
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
var k = keys[i];
var newCard = `
        <div class="row" id='Card'>
        <article class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="cards"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash icon">   </span>
            <hr class="divider"/>
            <h2 class="title">`+ jobs[k].JobTitle + `</h2>
            <div class="info">
            <hr class="divider"/>
            <p class="lead"><Strong>`+ jobs[k].JobDescription + 
            `</strong></p><a class="btn btn-lg center-block" onclick="location.href = 'Specialistscard.html';">Specialists</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </article>`;

container.innerHTML += newCard;}//END OF FOR
```

Make sure to add this `<div id="jobsContainer"></div>` in your html like the example